# Spring MVC DataTables Ajax Reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, datatables

I am looking for solution how to reload changes in my table with plugin DataTables.

My refresh method in Controller:

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/race/{id}/results/refreshTable", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Team> refreshTable(@PathVariable("id") int race_id) {
     //return list
}
```

Team class:

```html
public class Team implements Serializable{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int points;
    private int bonus;
    private int penalization;
    //another variables including getters and setters
}
```

Here is probably my problem because I don't know what to do right here to refresh changes in table :/

JS:

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "first_last_numbers",
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "bPaginate": false,
        ajax: { //I don't know what to do with this??????????
          type: "POST",
          url: "/race/${race.id}/results/refreshTable",
          dataType: "json",
         },                                   
    });
});

//call refresh
setInterval(function () {
  $('#myTable').DataTable().ajax.reload(null,false);                     
}, 5000);
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Your AJAX call to reload ` $('#myTable').DataTable().ajax.reload(null,false);  ` seems to be fine. What is the actual issue? You haven't described that.

Comment: I don't know how to define AJAX and how to change values in table.